# Some Tabs Not visible for other roles

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In netsuite, I have created one new centre tab and 7 sub tabs below the centre tab. Being the administrator I can see the centre tab and the 7 subtabs. But when I gave access to other users with different roles to access the centre tab and the 7 subtabs, then they are able to see only 3 of the 7 subtabs. Note that all the subtabs have the same access level in them and are almost identical.

gladiator

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try assigning yourself those roles as well and see if you can see them? Also, your users may need to logout and back in the changes to be seen. Also check that there aren't any subsidiary or location restrictions for those user/role/tab combinations.

Comment: Hello,

I allocated the role to myself and did see the same thing happening.

Comment: Client doesnt have subsidiary or location restrictions for those user/role/tab combinations.


this remain there even if i Logout.

My question is if they are not visible then they all should not be visible. Some are visible and some not, My say is if they are not visible then they all should be not visible. Partially, well thats my cause of concern

Comment: One of the differences between the tabs must be responsible. It might come down to a slow process of elimination